# How can I hide the last digit when I'm typing a password on my website on iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios, ipad

I have an input tag with password type on my website.

```
<input type="password">
```

With iPad or iPhone, it shows always the last letter when you are typing a password.

My problem is that I do a lot of demonstrations of my website with iPad.

I don't want that iPad shows the last letter when I'm typing my password.

Can I fix this by modifying something on my website?

Comment: Sure. Switch from an input type=password tag to a straight textbox, and write some javascript to record what's typed, but display *'s. You'll have to do some fancy work at post to swap the real values back in. Have fun!

Comment: How about creating a user that you don't care about or have a demo app/DB?

Comment: Yes or change the password regularly?

Comment: Or store the password and use autofill to populate the fields on log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "simplest" thing is probably to create a custom input which listens for the keys and stores the actual key values while just displaying • or * in the field.

Just attach a key listener and display a * for each letter you enter, so you know that you're actually adding input.

Type into the field on the left, I'm displaying what I'm collecting in the field on the right while only showing asterisks where you type.  It needs a bit of work to detect backspace and capitals and such, but you get the idea.
example on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d94P5/

### Example

```
<input type="text" id="password">
<input type="text" id="hiddenValue">​
```

### Javascript

```
var field = document.getElementById("password")
var realValue = "";
field.onkeydown = function(evt){
    realValue += String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode)      
    this.value = realValue.replace(/./g,"*");      
    document.getElementById("hiddenValue").value = realValue

    return false;   
}
```

Comment: -1? Why? I'm offering a totally workable solution to the stated problem. Granted it's a bit klugy, but the whole problem is extremely unusual and requires an unusual solution. Downvoting should be used for "wrong" answers. At the very least have the decency to comment as to what warranted the down vote.

Comment: I just up voted. I haven't tried it personally but think the idea could work.

Comment: Look at an actual iPhone keyboard at the bottom of an iPhone display.  See what happens to this keyboard image when you touch any key.  Even if the web page is black "*" on a black background.

Comment: For a real version you'll need to make it work properly with the delete key in case you make a mistake, plus it doesn't work with shift.

Comment: you're saying that the reason for downvoting is because I didn't write the entire code, but rather just provided the OP with the basic idea??  I even pointed out in my answer that it needs all those small bits added!

Comment: whether or not you did, you're implying that it's an incomplete answer, even as I state IN the answer that it's just a sketch of the idea that needs a little work to really be useful.

Answer (score 2):

No, iOS shows the last letter of the password typed by default and there is no way to disable that.

For demonstration purposes, you have a few options that I can think of. If using a projector, or TV-out, disconnect the device or turn off the screen while entering the password or you can set up a "demo" account for whatever you are going to demo.

By setting up a "demo" account *(and this is just a personal thought)*, you can continue without skipping a beat *(compared to turning off a screen, etc.)*, and if the viewers of your presentation see a "demo" account login / password it shouldn't matter too much, right?

Also, this should go without saying, if using a demo account, make sure it has limited access, obviously!

Comment: I know that I can not disable this in iOS.
I want know how I can disable this by modifying my site.
Maybe something like a input listener, when I type a letter, it change the letter with a "*".

Comment: You can't disable it through HTML, JS either.

Answer (score 2):

The iOS password control lets you paste a password into it (even the iTunes store password popup dialog).

Why don't you use a password app such as [pwSafe](http://app77.com/pwSafe/) to store and then copy the password to the clipboard, or even precopy the password into the clipboard before the demo? That way you haven't got to reinvent the password control, or mess around with demo accounts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a temporary password to a dummy account with strictly limited access, and configure your site to automatically disable that account and expire the password at the end of your demo hour.

Comment: Basically the same answer as mine.